# Can i not call directly a function on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I am new to learning pandas and have just learned python so my question may look silly. I created a function to change null values in a dataset. and i tried to call that function on few columns of my dataframe.

```
def impute_age(cols):
    age = cols[0]
    pclass = cols[1]
    
    if pd.isnull(Age):
        
        if pclass == 1:
            return 37
        
        elif pclass ==2:
            return 29
        
        else:
            return 23
    else:
        return Age
```

Then i called it like this:

```
train['Age'] = impute_age(train[['Age','Pclass']])
```

It is giving Key error: 0

i checked somewhere and he used like:

```
train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)
```

But in `python` we called function like above. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Your function is not designed in such a way that you can have a DateFrame be the input. I would recommend using `numpy.select` for this case.

Comment: If you want to use boolean indexing you should use `df.iloc[: , colIndex]` .  When you just use `0` pandas thinks it's the column label rather than index. So that's the reason of your error. But there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do on replacing NaN values. `numpy.where()` , `numpy.select()` and `df.where()` are such ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use it like

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def impute_age(age, pclass):
    if pd.isnull(age):
        if pclass == 1:
            return 37
        elif pclass ==2:
            return 29
        else:
            return 23
    else:
        return age

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 100], 'Pclass':[1,2,3,4]})
df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda row: impute_age(row['Age'], row['Pclass']), axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
   Age  Pclass
0   37       1
1   29       2
2   23       3
3  100       4
```